# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect openshift

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, openshift

I have an application on [`Openshift`](https://www.openshift.com) I'm trying to `connect` to `MySQL DB` my code is :

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.11.240.130:3306/"
        + DB_NAME;
public static String initConnection() {
    if (connection == null) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER_NAME,
                    PASSWORD);
            return "Connection Initialized!";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return "Connection Initialized!";
}
```

and in `index.jsp` code is :

```
<p><% out.print(""+com.measyou.DbManager.initConnection()); %> </p>
```

this code gives me

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

and `Caused by` :

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have referred [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai) and [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985771/jdbc-cant-connect-to-mysql-database-on-openshift?rq=1) as well, but Im unable to solve this problem. Please Help me in solving this one.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a scaled application, or is it running in a single gear?  Either way, you should be using OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST and OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT instead of hard-coding the IP and port.  And are you sure the mysqld is running?  Run the following:

`ps -ef | grep mysqld`

and you should see running processes.  Then run:

`netstat -plnt | grep $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT`

if it's running properly, you should see a line like this:

`tcp        0      0 127.11.240.130:3306          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      459740/mysqld`

if the process is not running, or it's not listening on the port as expected, then check the mysql logs in ~/mysql/log/ for errors.